# How this works: chr(($number >>6 )+192).chr(($number & 63)+128);

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte, chr

Can you please explain how this line of code is equivalent to the next code:

```
<?php
$string = chr( ( $number >> 6 ) + 192 ).chr( ( $number & 63 ) + 128 );
?>
```

Its equivalent to :

```
if ( $number >=128 && $number <=2047 ){

   $byte1 = 192 + (int)($number / 64); //= 192 + ( $number >> 6 )
   $byte2 = 128 + ($number % 64);      //= 128 + ( $number & 63 )
   $utf = chr($byte1).chr($byte2);
 }
```

for example entering number 1989 both produces `߅`

These codes are used for converting UNICODE Entities back to original UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Look up UTF-8 encoding at Wikipedia. They give a thorough description of how it works. This code is pretty straightforward once you understand the encoding.

Comment: the question is how (int)($number / 64) =? ( $number >> 6 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on top uses binary operators.
`>>` is right shift operator. It shifts the bit in the number to the right (towards more significant bits).

So `11110000 >> 2 = 00111100`

It's equivalent to division by powers of 2
`$number >> $n` is the same as `$number / pow(2,$n)`.

The `&` is the "bitwise and" operator. It compares respective bits on both numbers, and sets in result those, that are `1` in both numbers.

`11110000 & 01010101 = 01010000`

By and'ing `$number` with 63 (`001111111`) you get the remainder of dividing `$number` by 64 (aka the modulus), which is written `$number % 64`.

Answer (score 2):

`$number >> 6` is a binary shift-right operation, ie: `11000000 >> 6 == 00000011` equivalent to `$number / pow(2,6)` aka `$number / 64`

`$number & 63` is a binary `AND` with `00111111`

Both are much faster to do as binary operations since they deal with powers or two.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mchl's answer the reason for adding 192 in UTF sequence is to signal the start of byte information

192 - 11000000 - Start of 2 Byte sequence ( 128 + 64)

224 - 11100000 - Start of 3 Byte sequence ( 128 + 64 + 32)

240 - 11110000 - Start of 4 Byte sequence ( 128 + 64 + 32 + 16)

248 - 11111000 - Start of 5 Byte sequence (Restricted) (... + 8)

252 - 11111100 - Start of 6 Byte sequence (Restricted) (... + 4)

254 - 11111110 - Invalid

Table Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UTF-8&oldid=388157043

[UTF-8 byte range table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRQ1f.png)